# What does "Everything But Water" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

The swimsuit catalog is named 'Everything But Water".
I'm a bit confused about the meaning of this phrase.
Does it mean "*All you need is water*"?

Answer (score 8):

In the phrase "everything but water", **but** means **except**:

> Except; apart from; other than. ([Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/but))

It might mean that they're selling everything you need to go swimming except for the water itself.